# Different Lambda-GB-Seconds in billing and aws logs?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, lambda

I'm new to AWS and is trying out Lambda / Dynamo DB. I can't get the billing information for Lambda-GB-Seconds to add up as follows.

**General Lambda pricing information**

Lambda pricing information states 400,000 GB-seconds is available as a free tier each month for all customers.
I'm testing a 128MB instance, which means my nodejs Lambdas consume 128/1,024 = 1/8 of a GB-Second for each second it's running.
This is described here:
https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/pricing/

**My executions these first 3 days of March**

Using the "aws log" command i find that I have executed 76 requests in March for a total "Billed duration" of 70,700ms which is roughly 71 seconds runtime on a 128 MB instance. Example of one log line:

```
REPORT RequestId: a3431636-ff78-11e6-8717-6bee07e21e60  Duration: 1036.89 ms    Billed Duration: 1100 ms    Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 29 MB
```

If I calculate that from a 128MB instance to a 1GB instance to get GB-seconds it's 71s * (128 / 1,024) = 8.9s.
**Ie From my calculations I get that I have consumed roughly 9 GB-seconds  of compute time.**

**Billing report for March ( 3 days so far )**

Looking at my billing report for March so far it has no costs listed, but looking at Lambda billing it states consumed volumes:

```
AWS Lambda - Requests Free Tier - 1,000,000 Requests: 77 Request
AWS Lambda - Compute Free Tier - 400,000 GB-Seconds: 9.063 Lambda-GB-Second
```

**The question**

What am I missing? The number of requests roughly matches (76 vs 77), so that tells me I have found "all" the march executions. But how can the Billing console have calculated that I have consumed 9,063 Lambda-GB-Seconds, when I have a total runtime of 71 "128MB-seconds" which is roughly 9 Lambda-GB-Seconds. It's a factor 1000 times higher.
Any input appreciated!

Comment: hmm.. isn't that a decimal point? not a comma?

Comment: That must be it! Do I feel foolish... I guessed I had missed something, but not like this. ( . / , have "swapped" meaning in Sweden as a weak excuse) Thank you Kevin! (I mark your info as accepted solution if you put it as an answer :)